# Why can't I find the App Avro Phonetic even though the software center shows it as installed?

Tags: software-center

I installed the software Avro Phonetic via Terminal for being able to type in Bengali (Bangla) characters, and the Software Center shows it as installed. But I cannot find it when I want to use it. Can anyone show me way out?

Comment: Let me know if the answer below worked for you. If it works, consider accepting my answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will indicate that your problem is solved and help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ibus-avro` you have installed is not a separate software. It is a keyboard layout. Once you install it, you have to enable the layout to use it.

Here are the steps:

## Enable Avro keyboard layout

1. Go to System Menu at the top right corner of the desktop panel and
   select Settings, the Gears ⚙ icon.
2. Select the Keyboard tab from the left panel
   [image]
3. Click the <kbd>+</kbd> icon under the **Input Sources** to open **Add an Input Source** window.
   [image]
4. Click on the three dots at the bottom of the window to expose the
   search bar.
   [image]
5. Enter **Bangla** in the search bar and click on the <kbd>Other</kbd> button above.
   [image]
6. Select **Bangla (Avro Phonetic)** from the list. Click the <kbd>Add</kbd> button on the top right corner.
   [image]
7. Now you will see the Bangla (Avro Phonetic) has been added to input sources as shown above. See the <kbd>en</kbd> icon at the top right corner in the picture above. You will have a similar icon on your desktop. You will be able to switch between English and Bangla by clicking on that icon.

Alternately you can switch between English and Bangla by the keyboard shortcut of <kbd>Super/Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Space Bar</kbd>.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am still struggling. The icons you mention don't match with my desktop panel. My OS is Ubuntu 22.04. At the moment not able to give it enough time, too. As soon as it's done I'll surely acknowledge.

Comment: Yes, seems to be working. I'll have to work with it more to get used to it and be sure. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad that you figured it out. You can look at the keyboard layout from the icon on the top bar once you select Bangla (Avro Phonetic) from the list. You may also try other alternate bangla keyboard layouts using the method described above.